# Can't bind to 'expandedHeight' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-accordion'

Tags: angular, angular-material, accordion, angular7

I ran into this issue and there was no match to the answer so I thought I'd post this.

This issue is when using Angular Material accordion and attempting to use the expandedHeight property to customize the height of the accordion, you receive the error:

```
Can't bind to 'expandedHeight' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-accordion'.
```

The code may look like this:

```
<mat-accordion [expandedHeight]="'2em'">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>{{ headerText }}</mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    {{ content }}}
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, in this case, is simple.  Note that expandedHeight applies to the HEADER, not the accordion.  So the fix is to move the attribute to the panel component.

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header [expandedHeight]="'2em'">
        <mat-panel-title>{{ headerText }}</mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    {{ content }}}
</mat-accordion>
```